# Statistic for significance test comparing transition matrix to null

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, permutation-test, multivariate-distribution

I have several pitch sequences (mini songs), that look something like this when plotted as a pitch profile (piano roll):

[image]

I've coded each sequence in terms of its constituent interval sizes, and pooled all values together. Below is the transition matrix for interval bigrams, to show whether intervals of a given size are more likely followed by intervals of any other size:

[image]

This comes from interval sizes organised into pairs, with each considered twice, such that element2 of one pair becomes element1 of the next:

[image]

I'd like to do a significance test upon this transition matrix, against some null distribution with an equal number of pairs. I think this is equivalent to a permutation test but I'm not sure.

Assume for a second that an appropriate null is generated by sampling each of the intervals from a random distribution with mean 0 and SD 5 semitones, which produces something likes this:

[image]

My question is: which statistic is appropriate to perform the significance test on?

What I want to know is whether specific patterns emerge out of the distribution, over what might be expected from intervals that follow one another randomly.

A few rather vague hypotheses are available, such as:

- H_A: "after a large interval1 (>4 semitones), interval2 is likely to be smaller and in the opposite direction".
- H_B: "An interval2 is likely to be close in size to interval1"

This suggests particular null shapes to use, e.g. weighted towards one quadrant (H_A), or radially around the origin of the axes (H_B).

However, I wonder if I can test something more simple/general, like "in the empirical distribution, certain cells (interval bigrams) are more likely than others, leading to a few focal cells or sets of cells, as compared to the null distribution where bigrams solely converge onto the (0,0) point".

I know multivariate statistical tests [exist](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512383/what-is-a-generalisation-of-t-test-to-the-case-of-multivariate-distribution), but I'm not sure if that gets at my aim above.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like you aren't representing *pitches:* you appear to be representing successive *intervals* between pitches.  As far as your test goes, what would be a meaningful null hypothesis in your application?  Your situation doesn't seem to need such a test, nor would it benefit from the result.  Aren't you rather trying to *learn* about the patterns of intervals?

Comment: Indeed, I am representing successive intervals between pitches, so between P1-P2-P3 there'd be two successive intervals: P1-P2, P2-P3.

Comment: As for the test, I am trying to see if there *is* a pattern, assuming if there is one, it will take the shape described by the hypotheses I listed.

Comment: There obviously is a pattern, so go on from there.

Comment: You are right that a simple visual comparison of the empirical and the null distribution, or a simple eye-balling of the empirical one itself, should answer that question. However, here I am just responding to critics who would like to see a statistical test reported to support any claim that there is evidence for one hypothesis or another. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sure, but why belabor the obvious?  If you are looking for patterns in music, consider starting with a time-series representation of the data.  When graphed, it would look almost exactly like tablature and would show both intervals and durations.  Because people have looked hard at time series, that literature (on time series as well as one-dimensional stochastic processes generally) offers many procedures to explore patterns of all sorts.

Comment: I simplified my question for ease of understanding, but the data in question actually comes from pooling across several such tablature-like "mini songs", and the idea is to check those hypotheses about successions of intervals. I'm not sure it's possible (at least not visually/intuitively) without plotting interval bigrams as I did, as has inf act been previously done in that literature.

Comment: Because time series techniques focus on characterizing and measuring all kinds of complex patterns, they can do far more than this bigram diagram can.  (Which is not to deprecate it: it's a fine exploratory tool.) As a simple example, you could explore the Fourier Transform of a mini-song.

Comment: The Fourier Transform of a mini-song would indeed be meaningful to compute. I just wonder what type of FT I need, given that the mini-songs, while "continuous" (rather than discrete) signals, nonetheless don't occupy the time-domain fully but have gaps in them (see plot at the top of updated question). Matlab's `fft` at least seems to expect a signal's `y` values to each be defined at every timepoint `x`.

Comment: Ah, yes -- the rests.  One physically natural approach would be to represent this as a waveform, which will be continuous in time (its amplitude during the rests is zero).  That permits you to represent changes in amplitude (sound intensity) during the mini-song, too.